# Create new .NetCore MSTest project and get an error indicating 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, .net-core, mstest

I am trying to create a new MSTest V2 project.
I create a new MSTest .NetCore project and before I have done any changes I already get this error

The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) in file .nuget\packages\microsoft.net.test.sdk\16.5.0\build\netcoreapp2.1\Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk.Program.cs(3,12,3,24)

I am using VS2019 16.6.30204.135
I have installed Microsoft .Net Core SDK 3.1.102 and 2.1.402

UnitTest1.cs:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    namespace UnitTestProject2
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class UnitTest1
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public void TestMethod1()
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

build output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>MyProject\UnitTest1.cs(1,17,1,29): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
1>.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.test.sdk\16.5.0\build\netcoreapp2.1\Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk.Program.cs(3,12,3,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
1>MyProject\UnitTest1.cs(5,6,5,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestClassAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>MyProject\UnitTest1.cs(5,6,5,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>MyProject\UnitTest1.cs(8,10,8,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethodAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>MyProject\UnitTest1.cs(8,10,8,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>Done building project "MyProject.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1):

For Solving your problem you can reinstall the MSTest package or Update your VS to last vertion.

I had same problem for Morelinq package and reinstall it and re run my Vs.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Visual Studio 16.8.2 fixed it.